# Applying two classes in CSS for the same <hr> element but without specifying them

Tags: html, css, wordpress, separator

On my Wordress blog, I frequently use `<hr>` in blog posts. In other posts I use two `<hr>` per post - and in others I use no `<hr>`.

So right now this is in my CSS:

```
.entry-content hr {
  overflow: visible;  
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  border: 10px solid #74eda7;
  border-radius: 8px;
  color: green;
  text-align: center;
  }

.entry-content hr:after {
   content: "↓ INSPIRE ↓"; 
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -0.8em;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 0 0.25em;
    background: white;
```

which works fine unless I add another `<hr>` to a blog post and then I want a new set of attributes to be applied.

Is there anything I can please add so that a second instance of `<hr>` within any one blog post takes on a whole new set of attributes.

Something like this works:

```
.entry-content hr:nth-child(odd):after {
content: "↓ inspire 2X ↓";
}

.entry-content hr:nth-child(even):after {
content: "↓ INSPIRE ↓";
}
```

except when I have multiple blog posts per page, the odd and even makes it inconsistent across posts. The first `<hr>` should say "Inspire" and the 2nd on any blog post should say "inspire 2x" and a web page can have up to 7 blog posts in total.

I don't want to manually start adding class names into each blog post.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us more of your HTML - there must be something that tells it when a new blog post is being shown.

Comment: At the beginning of each post is something like: <article id="post-19324" class="post-19324 post type-post status-publish format-standard....</article>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `nth-child` with `nth-of-type`:

```css
.entry-content hr:nth-of-type(even):after {
content: "↓ inspire 2X ↓";
}

.entry-content hr:nth-of-type(odd):after {
content: "↓ INSPIRE ↓";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select an element in CSS by an attribute, and in this case you can select by an attribute starting with a particular string.

This snippet selects by article with ids starting with post-

```css
.entry-content article hr:nth-child(odd)::after {
  content: "↓ inspire 2X ↓";
  z-index: 1;
}

.entry-content article[id^="post-"] hr:nth-child(even)::after {
  content: "↓ INSPIRE ↓";
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  POST 19324:<br>
  <article id="post-19324" class="post-19324 post type-post status-publish format-standard">
    <hr>post 19324 has two hrs
    <hr>
  </article>
  <br>
  <br>POST 19325:<br>
  <article id="post-19325" class="post-19325 post type-post status-publish format-standard">
    <hr>post 19325 has one hr</article>
  <br>
  <br>POST 19326:<br>
  <article id="post-19326" class="post-19326 post type-post status-publish format-standard">
    <hr>post 19326 has one hr</article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
.entry-content hr:after {
  content: "↓ inspire 2X ↓";
}

.entry-content hr + hr:after {
  content: "↓ INSPIRE ↓";
}
```

Comment: Only the 'even' line was used in all instances of <hr>.

Comment: Add your HTML Code here

Comment: https://pastebin.com/MxjRLGHJ - that's a web page with one post displayed

Comment: For some reason it didn't work, but thanks.